# Performance: View vs. Subselect

Tags: sql, view, subquery

A little background:

I have a Log-Table with much information in it (around 10.000 entrys per week of using my webaaplication). I have a position-table, which is my main table (so the user works with positions in my application and can manipulate them etc.)
Now I want a `LastStateChangedDateTime`, so the `DateTime` of a event which I have in Log.

Now I can do this per 2 ways:

1) Per view.

I build a view in which I have the simple fields PositionID and LastStateChangedDateTime:

```
Select PositionID, Max(DateTime) as LastStateChangedTime from Position 
join Log on CAST(Position.PositionID as NVARCHAR) = Log.Message
where Event = 'PosStateChanged' 
group by PositionID
```

And can connect the view in my which select:

```
Select bla, MyView.DateTime 
from Positions [Much more joins here] 
     inner join MyView 
     on Positions.PositionID = MyView.PositionID
```

Or

2) Per Subselect, which will be like:

```
Select bla, LastChangedDateTime 
from Positions [Much more joins here] 
    inner join (Select PositionID, Max(DateTime) as LastStateChangedTime 
                from Position 
                join Log on CAST(Position.PositionID as NVARCHAR) = Log.Message
                where Event = 'PosStateChanged' AND PositionID = Positions.PositionID
                group by PositionID) etc.etc.
```

So, simple question: What of both ways should I go and why? What is faster and why?

Comment: A view is nothing more than a stored query, so the performance will be exactly the same in both scenarios. You could also try both methods, check the execution plans and see for yourself which performs better. With regards to which way you should go, the same rules apply as any other view, if you are going to reuse the same query in a lot of other queries, then create a view, if this is the only time you will use it then it is probably not worth it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statements are equal. A view is just the definition of a query, a placeholder so to say. When you use it in another Statement, the view's name gets replaced with the actual statement. So it is about readability and convenience and not about speed.

Some dbms offer special views, however, that store the actual query result. Oracle calls these materialized views. The idea is that if tables' data is rather constant for a long time, then why use the same complex query again and again. But then one must think of when to update the view.

But as said, normal views are simply names for pre-written SQL.

Comment: Are you sure about that? 
Because as far as I can understand it the view will be preloaded?
E.g. I have 100k logs in my log table and 5k Positions ... Then the view will show 5K Items (every LastChangeDate for a position)...

The question behind that is: Does the view load 5k items and THEN filter for the positionID, when on the other hand the subselect ONLY gets 1 row because the positionID will be applied directly?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Your second query is not valid. In your derived table (the sub-select) you access Positions.PositionID. You cannot do that. You must move `PositionID = Positions.PositionID` to the ON clause, and this gives you the same statement as with a view.

Comment: It's my understanding that Views have similar gains as Procs as having optimized query plans over raw execute.